# Laravel 5.4 - SoapClient not loaded from Job

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, docker, soap

I have a problem getting PHP's SoapClient to work in my Laravel Job.
I created queueable job where I import the SoapClient with `use SoapClient` but Laravel is not able to find it.

But when I use the SoapClient in my Controllers it works flawlessly.

I checked phpini(): SoapClient is definitely enabled.

Any Ideas?

My Job Code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Jobs;

use SoapClient;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use JWTAuth;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;


class ProcessQueuedRenderRequests implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

public function __construct()
{
}

public function handle()
{
    $soap = new SoapClient("http://mywsdl");
 ...
```

Errorlog:

```
[[2017-11-22 18:17:50] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /var/www/app/Jobs/ProcessQueuedRenderRequests.php:44
```

I use Docker with the Laradock configuration.
The joblistener ist started in this way:

```
docker-compose exec workspace bash

php artisan queue:listen
```

Comment: Stupid question, but needs to be asked - you snipped some lines above the SoapClient call, right? Just asking because it isn't on line 44. Also, remember that if you have queue listeners running you need to reload them when you've made a change to the code.

Comment: yes.. I snipped some lines. The `new SoapClient()` causes the error. I also tried reloading the listener a couple times.

Comment: And when you checked phpini, you checked both the one your web server is using and the one your cli uses, right?

Comment: that also came just came to my mind. Is it possible to check that from the cli?

Comment: Sure, try e.g. `php -i  | grep soap`

Comment: And of course, if it was recently installed try restarting php for good measure. :)

Comment: Found the problem. It soap was not installed in the workspace containter.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, glad you got it working! :)

Answer (score 0):

use
      `$soap = new \SoapClient("http://mywsdl");`
I had the same issue once.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Soap was not installed in the workspace container.

When I start the joblistener like this it works:

`docker-compose exec php-fpm bash
php artisan queue:listen`

Still a bit strange since should also be installed in the workspace container according to my .env file.